# Unable to deploy ear in weblogic 10.3.3

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

I'm facing problem to deploy ear in weblogic 10.3.3 having exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: zip:F:/Weblogic/domain/servers/myserver/tmp/_WL_user/ws-ear/lnygj9/APP-INF/lib/primefaces-3.1.1.1.jar
at weblogic.utils.zip.ZipURLConnection.connect(Handler.java:78)
at weblogic.utils.zip.ZipURLConnection.getInputStream(Handler.java:53)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(URLJarFile.java:195)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:50)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:80)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:104)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:71)
at com.sun.faces.config.AnnotationScanner.processClasspath(AnnotationScanner.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.config.AnnotationScanner.getAnnotatedClasses(AnnotationScanner.java:221)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:768)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:739)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:332)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:226)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1863)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3126)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1512)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:486)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:1267)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:409)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
```

I have added the primefaces3.1.1.1.jar in jsf project lib directory.
I does not found any helpful solution on on net. Is it weblogic10.3.3 version specific.

Please suggest.

Comment: Maybe you should further add the `.jar` files to the weblogic lib directory.

Comment: still this is not working having same error. :(

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for `primefaces-3.1.1.1.jar` within the EAR within a folder called `APP-INF/lib` - is that where you have placed it?

This is **not** the same as the `Weblogic server/lib` nor the `WEB-INF/lib`

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 options
1)Check if you have placed the primefaces jar in ear/WEB-INF/lib folder
2)Try adding the Primeface.jar in MANIFEST fileof the ear